# Can I list all *unavailable* projects in a Visual studio solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I have a solution with 90+ projects with lots of folders "hiding" the projects in the Solution explorer tree.
Due to a lengthy rebase with shaky merge I have some csproj files that are incorrect. Is there a way to get a list of these?

I can manually recurse the tree and look for all "YetAProject (unavailable)" projects but would prefer a faster and less manual way.

I tried building but as they are not available they are not compiled and hence leave no trace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Within the solution explorer simply enter into the search box `(unavailable)` and the list will be filtered.

[image: Filtered solution explorer]